# Why won't the 3D cursor move with an object on a bezier

Tags: animation

I'm working on something where I'm animating an object moving through the air while spinning and rotating. I tried using the 3D cursor as a pivot point at the centre of mass, but the cursor won't lock on or stick to my object. Even while setting the origin to the centre of an empty on my object, when I try to rotate that plane, the 3D cursor takes over and I'm forced to rotate using that. Is this something that just doesn't work with blender animation.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this page help: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html

Comment: hello, maybe show what you're trying to do with some screenshots, the 3D cursor won't count anymore when you'll animate, only the origin of the object, or the origin of its parent if it's the parent that moves

Answer (score 2):

The 3-D cursor should never move unless you click somewhere, or manually change its position properties in the view tab of the 3D Viewport editor’s sidebar. When you are not doing that, it should stay still.

To make an object pivot around an arbitrary point for an animation, I would recommend using an empty and parenting the object to that. The 3-D cursor pivot point is only for tool operations, and will not flow through into animation.